# How do i get my app publishing status via API

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

Every time you publish even a tiniest update for your app to google play, you have to wait for a review process to finish before an update will be published. This review process can take up to a week at worst (because poor google is struggling with COVID, boo-hoo).

Anyway, is there a way to know precisely when it is reviewed and published via some API? I know they have e-mail notifications, but i need to make this process more automated. I don't mind sending a request every few minutes to get the status of my app. So far I have researched google play console API, but I couldn't find any methods to get an app status.

Most likely, google (being stupid as usual), didn't provide any way to do this properly. Maybe I can do this via directly parsing a google play console HTML page? Of course if it isn't against google's ToS. Thanks.

Comment: +1
That's something strange as all other companies are functioning smoothly then why Google is struggling due to Covid!

Comment: Yes, they have Google Play Developer API and there is an end-point for getting the list of releses with their statuses, but I haven't tried it yet, so I just put this link in the comment and it may will be useful for you - https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks#Track

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no such API to get the status of published or pending on the console, the only option is to open your google console where you'll see the notification about what's the status of your app.

And for parsing the Console Html page, I don't think so Google will allow you to do that.
You can give it a try.

Comment: This is the correct answer, you can only have a rejection email, see my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/77010065/2127277

Answer (score 1):

Messaged Google Play Developer Support and got this answer:

> Currently, there is no API to retrieve the status of your apps. You can visit our document for current available APIs that you can use. We’re always adding new features and functionality, so please stay tuned.

However, the [Publish API](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher#publishing) exists which has [edit.tracks](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks/get) endpoint that returns a [track](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks#Track) and its [releases](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks#Release) including a [status](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/edits.tracks#Status):

- `statusUnspecified` Unspecified status.
- `draft` The release's APKs are not being served to users.
- `inProgress` The release's APKs are being served to a fraction of users, determined by 'userFraction'.
- `halted` The release's APKs will no longer be served to users. Users who already have these APKs are unaffected.
- `completed` The release will have no further changes. Its APKs are being served to all users, unless they are eligible to APKs of a more recent release.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your Google Play console, in All Apps chose a specific app you want to check.
In the dashboard tab exactly below your apps logo, you will see Production status.
Production status is INACTIVE if the app is not reviewed by Google and ACTIVE when the app is reviewed.
In the near app logo, you also have the view On Google Play link so you can click on it to see if your app published in Google Play or not.

See the photo with the inactive app:

[image]

Photo with an active app:

[image]

For automation maybe you can write some code and use View On Google Play link
and depend on link results to get active or inactive return info.
For example, if the app is not in the store link return:

> We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround: you can send a GET request to the following URL, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your-package-name". If it returns an HTTP response of 200, it means the application is published. If it returns 404, it indicates that the application is either in review or has been rejected.

Comment: This jsut tell you if an app exist, not if a new version of it is approved